# How to make an app wait for an input

Tags: android, dialog, wait

I am trying to get an input from another method then using that input afterwards, but the app does not wait for an input.

The code that I'm running is

```
case (R.id.menuSort):
         sSort = sortPopup();
         layout.removeAllViews();                           
         arrlst.clear();
         checkLogs();
```

where sortPopup is a method that creates a dialog and returns a string. When I click a button, the removeAllViews, clear and checkLogs function all start before I select an option from the dialog.

I have attempted to used wait and notify, but even after reading several threads with this similar issue I am unable to achieve my goal without the program crashing.

Is there a way to prevent the 3 functions from starting before a result is achieved from the sortPopup method?

The onPopup code is as follows

```
    public String sortPopup() {
    initializePopup(arrsSort);
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Select Sort")
            .setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    if (arrsSort[which] == "Ascending") {
                        sChoice = "ASC";
                    } else {
                        sChoice = "DESC";
                    }

                }
            }).create().show();

    return sChoice;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code this way:

```
public void sortPopup() {
    initializePopup(arrsSort);
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Select Sort")
            .setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    if (arrsSort[which] == "Ascending") {
                        sChoice = "ASC";
                    } else {
                        sChoice = "DESC";
                    }

                    layout.removeAllViews();
                    arrlst.clear();
                    checkLogs();
                }
            }).create().show();
      //You cant try call checkLogs() here
}
```

This way the code don't need any waits...

Comment: The method with the dialog is in a different method though. How would I go by using the onDismiss listener for a dialog in another method?

Comment: It depends on how you created the dialog... Add the sortPopUp code and I can see what i can do ;)

Comment: It's a bad idea to run code in the `onDismiss` method because dialog can be dismissed not only by clicking 'Ok' but also by clicking 'Cancel' and during configuration changes(for example screen orientation). See my answer below.

Comment: You're right but with the code I saw i cant guess how many buttons he has... that's why i gave the onDismiss idea and asked for more code :/

Comment: If your variables layout and arrlst are in the class you can call them in the function onClick... Doing all the code on the function onClick you don't need any waits.

Comment: The issue with that code is that checkLogs() is not in the same class as sortPopup(). I extended the class with sortPopup() in the class with checkLogs(). I'm not sure how to call a method from an extended class.

Answer (score 0):

You can create and show a dialog in the following way:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mActivity);
builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // Call your methods that wait for dialog input.
    }
});
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();
```